# C#: Crawl a page with asynchronous method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpclient

I'm coding a plug-in for Excel. I'd like to add a new method to excel that can crawl a web page and get back the html code.

my problem is that i have a lot of URLs to proces and if I use a sync method, it will take a lot of time and freeze my excel.

let say, i have a cell A1 which contains "http://www.google.com", and in A2, my method "=downloadHtml(A1)".

I'm using HttpClient because it is already handling Async. So here is my code :

```
static void Main()
{
    GetWebPage(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
}
static async void GetWebPage(Uri URI)
{
    string html = await HttpGetAsync(URI);
    //Do other operations with html code
    Console.WriteLine(html);
}
static async Task<string> HttpGetAsync(Uri URI)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
        Task<Stream> result = hc.GetStreamAsync(URI);

        Stream vs = await result;
        StreamReader am = new StreamReader(vs);

        return await am.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        switch (ex.Status)
        {
            case WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure:
                Console.WriteLine("domain_not_found");
                break;
            //Catch other exceptions here
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

The probem is that, when i run the program, the program exits before the task complete.

If i add a

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

the program will not exit do to the readline instruction, and after a couple of seconds, i see the html printed into my screen (du to the console.writeline instruction). So the program works.

how can i handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

`GetWebPage` is a fire-and-forget method (an `async void`), so you cannot wait for it to finish.

You should be using this instead:

```
static void Main()
{
    string html = Task.Run(() => HttpGetAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com"))).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    //Do other operations with html code
    Console.WriteLine(html);
}
```

Also, you could simplify the download code to this:

```
using (var HttpClient hc = new HttpClient())
{
    return await hc.GetStringAsync(URI);
}
```

Comment: yes thank you for your answer. i tried this and it now waiting for the result. but it still block my excel, i mean when i run the function for several lines, excel is not handling it asynchronously. do you have an idea about how make excel doing this ? by the way, i'm using ExcelDna as a library to do this [ExcelDna ](http://exceldna.codeplex.com/documentation)

Comment: you code don't fix my issue but speed my code up... i found this in the documentation which fix my problem [http://exceldna.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Asynchronous%20Functions&referringTitle=Documentation](Asynchronous Functions). thank you anyway for your help :)